# Sikuli for Browser Testing -?

Tags: sikuli

All though we have multiple sites (like spoon) to get us help with browser testing, how about using Sikuli for cross / multiple browser testing? Has any one tried it and can share whether it works or not?

Many times we need to test the same functionality in different browsers. For an example you test whether text boxes for username and password on Login Page appear exactly same in FF and Chrome as they appear on IE. Similarly you verify some label, table or other web page components across multiple browsers.

Can we use Sikuli to do this, for an example:

1. Open IE & send F11 for Full Screen View *
2. Navigate to Login Page
3. Take a Screenshot and save
4. Now, open FF and do same steps 1 to 3
5. Next
6. Compare two images saved previously and generate results (Sikuli generate quite a good result of image comparison).

*Full screen view to make sure we compare apple with apple i.e. whole screen with whole screen of other browser.

Off course, nothing can replace human eye in browser or GUI testing, but doing above can definitively save good amount of time we spend in browser testing. At least, less-important functionality or screen can be verified by Sikuli and rest of them can still be done manually as done right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parva,

At the company I work for we have implemented Sikuli into our test suite and it works **GREAT!** across all browsers. I'm not sure if you're using an IDE for your test framework, but here we use SpringSource ToolSuite because our project lives within it already.

We implemented Sikuli to hit the different browsers we wanted it to by creating a properties file within our resource bundle. This properties file had the information for the base.url, base.login, and browser.options. When we write our test scripts using Selenium 2 we are sure to clarify which url, login, and browser(s) we want the test suites to run against.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

As long as you always run yout tests in the same condition the test screenshots were taken, yes, it's ok. There is another way of taking smaller screenshots of elements on your page and checking that they appear.

Why don't you use Selenium if you have web content to check? I'm sure you will have more flexibility to verify different actions. Or Selenium combined with Sikuli to have even more power...

Answer (score 0):

Sikuli would be a better platform for GUI related stuffs other than browser ie for any applications in desktop, but regarding browsers selenium would be the best tool rather than sikuli.